# Рекурсия в функции PHP

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
function getUser($full_name, $social_id) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `full_name` = '$full_name' AND `social_id` = '$social_id'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        if (setUser($full_name, $social_id)) {
            getUser($full_name, $social_id);
        }
    }

    closeDB();

    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}

function setUser($full_name, $social_id) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` SET `full_name` = '$full_name', `social_id` = '$social_id'");
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

    closeDB();

    return $id;
}
```

Суть в следящем: Вызываться функция `getUser`, если такой `user` уже есть, то вернуть о нем информацию. Если нету, то задать его, и вернуть информацию визовом функции `getUser`. Почему-то идет зацикливание. В базе каждую секунду добавляться одинаковый user

Comment: потому что insert не отрабатывает http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Как минимум стоит сделать поле username и добавить ему уникальный индекс, тогда одинаковые у вас появляться не будут при повторной попытке записи одного и того же пользователя вы словите ошибки. И поищите все места вызовы метода setUser.

Comment: И ещё что делают методы connectDB и closeDB? Они реально поднимают и закрывают коннект к БД?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте возвращать значение getUser, завершая тем самым выполнение функции

```
if (setUser($full_name, $social_id)) {
            return(getUser($full_name, $social_id));
        }
```

У меня правда и без этого заработало, но я не знаю, как у вас реализованы connectDB и closeDB. При рекурсивном вызове closeDB не срабатывает, а после вызова срабатывает, когда соединение уже и так закрыто.

Comment: Может еще с поиском проблемы, т.к. insert явно работает, а getUser нет. Моя БД: `CREATE TABLE `test`.`users` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `full_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `social_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
 $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

вместо

```
 $id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
```

Comment: прежде чем ответить прочитайте вопрос

Comment: Не помогло. Insert у меня работает и mysqli_insert_id($mysqli) возвращает значение > 0

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    if (setUser($full_name, $social_id)) {
        getUser($full_name, $social_id);
    }
}
```

на

```
if($result->num_rows == 0){ // проверяем количество записей в результате
    if (setUser($full_name, $social_id)) {
        return getUser($full_name, $social_id); // Прерываем дальнейшее выполнение
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функции правильные, проблема в максимальном значении типа int в БД. Заменил на bigint. Все работает